How do you get start and end date parameters in a direct query to work in power bi like in tableau
In sql I have a query
Declare @startdate as datetime = ‘4/1/24’
Declare @enddate as datetime = ‘4/8/24’
Select *
From Table
Where timestamp between @startdate and @enddate
I can easily transfer this query to tableau by creating parameters, deleting the declare statements, and inserting my tableau parameters in place of @startdate and @enddate.
How do you input parameters into power bi that would take the place of @startdate and @enddate.
I’ve spent a day googling how to do this and and the closest I’ve gotten is inputting parameters into the let statement prior to the source, but the parameters don’t work
